# Check share is a drive or a folder

Tags: vb6

In vb6 i want to differentiate between shared folder and shared drive.

If in PC1 D:\ is shared as with share name `myshare` then shared folder

And in PC1 if D:\myfiles shared with share name `myshareddrive` then it is shared drive.

I mean I will be getting inputs like `\\pc1\\myshare` amd `\\pc1\\myshareddrive` . So now i am not able to find whether they are shared foder or a shared drive.

Answer (score 4):

Presuming that you are using the SMB protocol (used for Windows file shares), there is no portable way to achieve this as the protocol does not communicate the remote path name. There is normally no use for such a feature and it could provide potentially useful information for would-be attackers.

If this is on Windows and you have administrative access, it is possible to query the remote path name via WMI which can be accessed remotely (with authentication).

The simplest way to do this would be to parse the output from `wmic.exe` which is available on all Windows platforms since Windows XP (excl. Home Edition) ([related superuser.com question](https://superuser.com/questions/149794/how-do-i-get-the-fully-qualified-path-of-a-share-in-windows)):

```
wmic /node:pc1 share where "name like 'myshare'" get path
```

Which should produce output along the lines of:

```
Path
D:\myfiles
```

To make this work *within* VB6 (without running other programs), you will need to use COM to query WMI:

```
Dim results As Object
results = GetObject("winmgmts:\\pc1").ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Share WHERE Name LIKE ""myshare""")

Dim pathName As String

If Len(results) > 0 Then
    pathName = results(0).Path
Else
    ' Throw exception instead? Could not find the share.
    pathName = ""
End If
```

I have handled neither authentication (for remote use etc.) nor error checking.

*Disclaimer: I have only tested the VBScript equivalent of the above code and not itself.*